# Can not start special firefox with Json configuration on Selenium 3

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

i using Selenium Grid and configuring the node and hub by Json
here is my json

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "browser-version": "38.8.0",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "firefox_binary": "C:/Program Files (x86)/secutix/Matterhorn_V3/FireFoxPortableESR/App/Firefox/firefox.exe",
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 5568,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

I started Hub (fine)

I started Node (fine)

 But when i run serenity test by maven cmd "mvn clean verify"
there are only Current Firefox ver 45.6 was created. The FireFoxPortableESR is none. 
*In case, change Selenium-server-standalon from 3.0 to 2.53, it working okay.* 

**so how to call FireFoxPortableESR when use Selenium 3.0***

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below two keys to run `Firefox` with `Selenium V3.0`

```
{
"capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "browser-version": "38.8.0",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      **"webdriver.gecko.driver" : "path to gecko driver"** -----> add path to gecko driver
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 5568,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
  "marionette" : true  ------------------> add marionette = true
}
```